# making sense of event value in GA

Tags: google-analytics

I am inheriting a web app which is connected to Google Analytics. The app sends a custom event in the following fashion:

```
 ("Operations","Main Operation", null, timeTaken)
```

where timeTaken is a variable that is taken to finish processing a bunch of data that gets displayed to the user then, based on setInterval of javascript. Now in the GA dashboard I see the following (after I click on Operations):
[image]

My question is what is this data telling me exactly?

Answer (score 0):

**Total events** 1.000.300 is the number of times events occurred.

**Unique events** 83.300 is a count of the number of times an event with the category/action/label value was seen at least once within a session (so if for an user in a session this event is sent 3 times, the count of unique event is 1).

timeTaken is fourth parameter, so it is the **event value** of the event that probably is always 30 (so if for an user in a session this event is sent 3 times, the event value, in total, is 90: 30+30+30).